# Validation for erroneous/boundry data

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

I am using this to check data has been entered into a form when submitted:

```
else if(document.getElementById('fname').value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length == 0) {
    alert('Please Insert your first name.');
    return false;
} else if(document.getElementById('lname').value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length == 0) {
     alert('Please Insert your last name.');
     return false;  
}
```

I would like it to check that no numbers has been entered and also that its not above say 10 characters. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check Number in text**

```
// Check given string contain number or not
// Return true is string contain number otherwise false
function containNumbers(text) {
    return /\d/.test(text);
}

if(containNumbers(document.getElementById("fname").value)) { 
      alert('Text contain number'); 
}
```

**Limit on length**

```
// Check text length
if (document.getElementById("fname").value.length >10 ) {

      // Validation code
}
```

**Both for non numeric and length**

```
var first_name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
   if (first_name.length >10 || containNumbers(first_name)) {

             // Validation code
   }
```

Comment: That worked for numbers thanks! is there a way I can also max the character entry?

Answer (score -1):

To check if the entered number is a number, do this:

```
// first, normalize your parameters (trimming in this case):
var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

if ( typeof lname == "number" ) {
    // its a number... float or int
}
if ( lname.length < 10 ) {
    // its too short...
}
if ( lname.length > 100 ) {
    // its too long...
}
// etc
```